# GitHub Action Gradle buildBootImage

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, github-actions, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Spring boot 2.3 onwards comes with Gradle tasks buildBootImage which creates a container and by default pushes it to docker.io/library. How can this task be customized, in the context of Gradle running in GitHub action to push the container to GHCR, ECR, or GCR; ie, when GitHub action executes ./gradlew buildBootImage

Gradle's buildBootImage task comes with the below config parameters block, what's the best way to set these values within the build script and how do we pass these values from GitHub actions?

```
tasks.getByName<BootBuildImage>("bootBuildImage") {
    imageName = "bestway to set image name"
    isPublish = true
    docker {
        publishRegistry {
            url = "best way to set container registry URL"
            username = "best way to set user name for CR"
            password = "best way to set password for CR"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know enough about authentication to the hosted registries to answer the question you've asked, but the auth options provided by the Spring Boot `bootBuildImage` task are limited to username/password basic auth. If any of the registries require more sophisticated auth, you'll likely need to build the image using Spring Boot then push it using different GH Actions plugins.